# Magento2 Testing

Tags: magento2, testing

For a beginner, testing in Magento2 is quite confusing-

- Functional tests- there is `dev\tests\functional\tests\app`, which contains tests.
  DevDocs says we need to install MTF. is MTF needed for running with Selenium, or i can run with Magento alone.
- Unit tests, does that have to be written in module directory of `dev/tests/unit` folder.

Comment: We've tried to make testing documentation as simple as possible [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/mtf/mtf.html). If it's still too confusing, please let us know how we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MTF based on Selenium, so you cannot run it without.

Unit test should be written in module folder. In future I believe, all tests will be placed in module dir

Comment: What about app folder in functional..what purpose it serves?

Comment: @huzefam, the `dev\tests\functional\tests\app` has similar structure to `app\code`

Comment: @KAndy, in nearest future only unit tests will be located in module folders, because in most cases functional and integration tests are used only by core developers.

Comment: @jonijones, It is problem. Any good developer must write integration tests for their modules

Comment: I agree with you, but for most developers which use some module, tests are not needed. If tests will be included into module - they will increase package size, but as I said, most of developers will not use this tests.